# Slopes with opposing signs provided by two methods

Tags: r, logistic, lsmeans

I have come across a situation where I am estimating trends in two different ways and the results have opposite signs. Specifically, the R functions `emtrends` and `ggeffect` are giving me contrasting results about the slope of a relationship. The relationship I'm investigating is whether seed predation changes across an elevational gradient in either of the years 2018 or 2019. The `emtrends` code looks like this:

```
test(emtrends(GLMM, pairwise ~ year, var = 'elevation.scaled', cov.reduce = range), null = 0)
```

The output looks like this:

```
$emtrends
 year      elevation.scaled.trend    SE  df z.ratio p.value
 2018                       -1.26 0.470 Inf -2.690  0.0071 
 2019                       -2.38 0.554 Inf -4.291  <.0001 

Results are averaged over the levels of: elevation.scaled, transect, date, temperature, invert.abundance
```

Looking under the elevation.scaled.trend column, seed predation seems to decline across elevation in both years.

This is at odds with the slope I get from this `ggeffect` code:

```
ggeffect(model, c('elevation.scaled', 'year'))
```

```
# year = 2018
      x predicted std.error conf.low conf.high
 -1.607     0.544     0.351    0.375     0.703
 -1.278     0.547     0.286    0.408     0.679
 -0.510     0.555     0.185    0.465     0.642
  0.064     0.561     0.205    0.461     0.657
  0.680     0.568     0.304    0.420     0.705
  1.293     0.574     0.431    0.367     0.758

# year = 2019
      x predicted std.error conf.low conf.high
 -1.607     0.859     0.403    0.734     0.930
 -1.278     0.810     0.325    0.693     0.890
 -0.510     0.653     0.226    0.547     0.745
  0.064     0.505     0.285    0.368     0.641
  0.680     0.345     0.427    0.186     0.549
  1.293     0.215     0.593    0.079     0.467
```

Looking within the year 2018, the predicted values (proportion of seeds eaten) increases ever so slightly across the elevational gradient, from 0.544 to 0.574.

So `emtrends` tells me the slope is negative and `ggeffect` tells me (indirectly) the slope is positive. What is going on here?

Comment: I am really annoyed that this question was put on hold. It is definitely about statistics and about trying to understand some conflicting results. I put some effort into providing a useful answer, and it is not one that can be found using your standard resources. Please remove the hold.

Answer (score 3):

I do not know the details of the model, but I am quite sure that it includes one or more interactions between `elevation.scaled` and other predictor(s).

There are two aspects of this that I see that can easily cause such a Simpson's Paradox-like issue.

1. The use of `cov.reduce = range` in the `emtrends()` call; thus, the frame of reference used for the `emtrends` results does not match that of the `ggeffects` results.
2. The annotation `Results are averaged over the levels of: elevation.scaled, transect, date, temperature`; thus, there are several predictors in the model that can affect the results.

Results from `emmeans()` and `emtrends()` depend on a *reference grid*: see the ["basics" vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emmeans/vignettes/basics.html) for discussion. The `cov.reduce` specification instructs that two reference levels be used for each numeric predictor -- the minimum and maximum. If any of the predictors are factors (e.g. `transect`?), the levels of those factors are used as the reference levels. The reference grid then consists of all combinations of the reference levels.

At each grid point, we have an estimate of the `elevation.scaled` trend; and those trends are averaged over the reference levels of four factors to obtain the results shown in the table; each estimate shown is thus the average of at least $2^4=16$ estimated slopes. If anything interacts with `elevation.scaled`, those slopes will not all be equal. They can vary wildly depending on how distant are the extrema of the predictors; and so potentially almost anything can happen when they are averaged together.

To see the details of the reference grid, just omit the `specs` argument:

```
trg1 <- emtrends(GLMM, , var = 'elevation.scaled', cov.reduce = range)
trg1             ### shows the structure
summary(trg1)    ### shows the estimated slopes
```

The `ggeffects` output, on the other hand, isimplicitly based on a reference grid where each numeric predictor is replaced by its average. That is also the default used in `emtrends()`, but it was overridden by the `cov.reduce` argument. I suggest trying:

```
trg2 <- emtrends(GLMM, , var = 'elevation.scaled', at = list(year = 2018:2019))
test(emmeans(trg2, pairwise ~ year))

### OR ###
test(emtrends(GLMM, pairwise ~ year, var = 'elevation.scaled', 
    at = list(year = 2018:2019)))
```

[The `at` part may be omitted if `year` is a factor.]
If all of the predictors are numeric, the reference grid, `trg2`, has only two nodes -- one for each year, and the estimates are the slopes at the average predictor values. If any of the predictors are factors, there will be more nodes, and only the factors will be averaged over in the final results.

I am betting that this will yield comparable results to what was obtained with `ggeffects`.

### Reproducible illustration

Using a built-in dataset...

```
R> foo <- lm(Infant.Mortality ~ Fertility*Agriculture*Education*Catholic, 
+      data = swiss)

R> emtrends(foo, "Catholic", "Fertility", cov.reduce = range)
NOTE: Results may be misleading due to involvement in interactions
 Catholic Fertility.trend    SE df lower.CL upper.CL
     2.15           0.127 0.370 31   -0.628    0.883
   100.00           0.236 0.298 31   -0.371    0.844

Results are averaged over the levels of: Fertility, Agriculture, Education 
Confidence level used: 0.95

R> emtrends(foo, "Catholic", "Fertility", at = list(Catholic=c(2.15,100)))
NOTE: Results may be misleading due to involvement in interactions
 Catholic Fertility.trend    SE df lower.CL upper.CL
     2.15          0.2056 0.116 31  -0.0318    0.443
   100.00         -0.0137 0.138 31  -0.2949    0.267

Confidence level used: 0.95
```

Note the two very different results that are explainable only by the choice of reference grid.

Comment: Note: Version 1.4.2 or higher of **emmeans** is needed to obtain the reference grids in the way that is described. With an earlier version, use `trg1 <- .Last.ref.grid` immediately after the `emtrends` call.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @rvl for your speedy answer. You were right that my issue partly stemmed from the `cov.reduce = range` argument. However, even if I removed the `cov.reduce` argument, I was still getting contrasting slopes provided by `emtrends` and `ggeffect`. This is my code adapted from your example:

```
emmGrid.GLMM <- emtrends(GLMM, var = 'elevation.scaled')  
test(emmeans(emmGrid.GLMM, pairwise ~ year))  

$emtrends
 year elevation.scaled.trend    SE  df z.ratio p.value
 2018                  -1.24 0.389 Inf -3.194  0.0014 
 2019                  -2.35 0.500 Inf -4.709  <.0001 

Results are averaged over the levels of: transect
```

Without the `cov.reduce` argument, the slopes for both years are still negative. Looking again at the output of `ggeffect`, we see the slope for 2018 is still slightly positive. This is unsurprising given we haven't fiddled with the ggeffect code yet.

```
ggeffect(five2X, c('elevation.scaled', 'year')) 

# year = 2018
      x predicted std.error conf.low conf.high
 -1.607     0.544     0.351    0.375     0.703
 -1.278     0.547     0.286    0.408     0.679
 -0.510     0.555     0.185    0.465     0.642
  0.064     0.561     0.205    0.461     0.657
  0.680     0.568     0.304    0.420     0.705
  1.293     0.574     0.431    0.367     0.758

# year = 2019
      x predicted std.error conf.low conf.high
 -1.607     0.859     0.403    0.734     0.930
 -1.278     0.810     0.325    0.693     0.890
 -0.510     0.653     0.226    0.547     0.745
  0.064     0.505     0.285    0.368     0.641
  0.680     0.345     0.427    0.186     0.549
  1.293     0.215     0.593    0.079     0.467
```

However, I played around with the code you provided and eventually found out a solution. The solution is to find out what values of the numeric predictors the function `emtrends` is using. I did this by simply calling the reference grid (I think that's what its called) object I created earlier.

```
emmGrid.GLMM

'emmGrid' object with variables:
    elevation.scaled = -0.20261
    transect = Hailstone Butte, Nakiska, Moose Mountain
    date = -1.4071e-15
    year = 2018, 2019
    invert.abundance = -5.2836e-17
    temperature = 2.3317e-16
```

I then used these values to do what the `ggeffect` function was doing. That is, predicting the proportion of seeds eaten at each scaled elevation. `ggeffect` won't let the user specify these values, so I switched to the similar `ggemmeans` function, plugged in the above values, and got a much more negative slope. Here's the code.

```
ggemmeans(five2X, c('elevation.scaled', 'year'), condition = c(elevation.scaled = -0.20261, date = -1.4071e-15, invert.abundance = -5.2836e-17, temperature = 2.3317e-16))   

# year = 2018
      x predicted std.error conf.low conf.high
 -1.607     0.783     0.564    0.544     0.916
 -1.278     0.705     0.453    0.496     0.853
 -0.510     0.479     0.261    0.356     0.606
  0.064     0.311     0.287    0.204     0.442
  0.680     0.173     0.457    0.079     0.339
  1.293     0.089     0.670    0.026     0.267

# year = 2019
      x predicted std.error conf.low conf.high
 -1.607     0.948     0.663    0.833     0.985
 -1.278     0.894     0.532    0.749     0.960
 -0.510     0.581     0.358    0.407     0.737
  0.064     0.264     0.453    0.129     0.466
  0.680     0.078     0.686    0.021     0.244
  1.293     0.019     0.961    0.003     0.116
```

Comment: Odd. I had assumed that ggeffects() would center around the covariate means. Not sure why it didn’t, but I don’t use that package.